# Want to update 2nd level array object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Following is my one collection response, wan't to update inventory value from following collection..

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "sku": "V4696-DR-V33",
    "options": [
        {
            "sku": "8903689984338",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "code": "AND1",
                    "zipcode": "110070",
                    "id" : 101010,
                    "inventory": 12
                },
                {
                    "code": "AND2",
                    "zipcode": "201010",
                    "id" : 101010,
                    "inventory": 10
                }
            ],
            "price": 2199,
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "size": "14"
        },
        {
            "sku": "1742564789",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "code": "AND1",
                    "zipcode": "110070",
                    "id" : 101010,
                    "inventory": 21
                },
                {
                    "code": "AND2",
                    "zipcode": "201010",
                    "id" : 101010,
                    "inventory": 20
                }
            ],
            "price": 2199,
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "size": "16"
        },
    ]
}
```

want to update all inventory value to 0 then what should i have to do..?
want any simple or single mongo query to update my all documents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with an atomic update as the field you want updated is embedded within a nested structure that the [positional **`$`** update operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will not be able to reach if using a single update operation that uses such positional operator to identify the array element position. There's an outsanding issue for this at http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

As a workaround, you will need to loop through your collection with a cursor and for each document within the cursor, gather data about the index position of the inventory field. You will then use this data later on in the loop as the update operation parameters to correctly identify the desired field to update.

If your collection is not that humongous, the intuition above can be implemented using the **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** method of the cursor to do the iteration and getting the index data for all the arrays involved. The following demonstrates this approach for small datasets (assuming your collection is named `inventory`):

```
db.inventory.find({"options.stores.inventory": { "$exists": true, "$ne": 0 }}).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var options = doc.options; 
    for (var optionIndex = 0; optionIndex < options.length; optionIndex++){ 
        var stores = options[optionIndex].stores
        for (var storeIndex = 0; storeIndex < stores.length; storeIndex++){ 
            var updateOperatorDocument = {};
            updateOperatorDocument["options."+optionIndex+".stores."+storeIndex+".inventory"] = 0
            db.inventory.update(
                { "_id": doc._id },
                { "$set": updateOperatorDocument }
            );
        }        
    } 
});
```

---

For improved performance especially when dealing with large collections, take advantage of using a **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API for updating the collection efficiently in bulk as you will be sending the operations to the server in batches (for example, say a batch size of 500). This gives you much better performance since you won't be sending every request to the server but just once in every 500 requests, thus making your updates more efficient and quicker.

The following examples demonstrate using the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API available in MongoDB versions `>= 2.6` and `< 3.2`.

```
var bulkUpdateOps = db.inventory.initializeUnOrderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;

db.inventory.find({"options.stores.inventory": { "$exists": true, "$ne": 0 }}).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var options = doc.options; 
    for (var optionIndex = 0; optionIndex < options.length; optionIndex++){ 
        var stores = options[optionIndex].stores
        for (var storeIndex = 0; storeIndex < stores.length; storeIndex++){ 
            var updateOperatorDocument = {};
            updateOperatorDocument["options."+optionIndex+".stores."+storeIndex+".inventory"] = 0
            bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id": doc._id }).update({ "$set": updateOperatorDocument })
        }        
    }     
    counter++;  // increment counter for batch limit
    if (counter % 500 == 0) { 
        // execute the bulk update operation in batches of 500
        bulkUpdateOps.execute(); 
        // Re-initialize the bulk update operations object
        bulkUpdateOps = db.inventory.initializeUnOrderedBulkOp();
    } 
})

// Clean up remaining operation in the queue
if (counter % 500 != 0) { bulkUpdateOps.execute(); }
```

---

The next example applies to the new MongoDB version 3.2 which has since [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API and provided a newer set of apis using **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)**.

It uses the same cursors as above but creates the arrays with the bulk operations using the same **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** cursor method to push each bulk write document to the array:

```
var cursor = db.inventory.find({"options.stores.inventory": { "$exists": true, "$ne": 0 }}),
    bulkUpdateOps = [];

cursor.forEach(function(doc){ 
    var options = doc.options; 
    for (var optionIndex = 0; optionIndex < options.length; optionIndex++){ 
        var stores = options[optionIndex].stores
        for (var storeIndex = 0; storeIndex < stores.length; storeIndex++){ 
            var updateOperatorDocument = {};
            updateOperatorDocument["options."+optionIndex+".stores."+storeIndex+".inventory"] = 0
            bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
                "updateOne": {
                    "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
                    "update": { "$set": updateOperatorDocument }
                 }
            });
        }        
    }
});         

db.inventory.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
```

**Write Result for Sample data**

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "deletedCount" : 0,
    "insertedCount" : 0,
    "matchedCount" : 4,
    "upsertedCount" : 0,
    "insertedIds" : {},
    "upsertedIds" : {}
}
```